# Filling in time gaps in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, date, time, series

I have the following in excel sheet:

```
    start                   end               value
1   26/11/2014 13:00    26/11/2014 20:00    decreasing
2   26/11/2014 20:00    27/11/2014 09:00    increasing
```

I would like to transfer the above table to a table in which each row time is opened and filled in with the `value`. The time gap is filled in from the `start` time to the `end` time - 1, as followed:

```
     date       hour        value
1   26/11/2014  13:00   decreasing
2   26/11/2014  14:00   decreasing
3   26/11/2014  15:00   decreasing
4   26/11/2014  16:00   decreasing
5   26/11/2014  17:00   decreasing
6   26/11/2014  18:00   decreasing
7   26/11/2014  19:00   decreasing
8   26/11/2014  20:00   increasing
9   26/11/2014  21:00   increasing
10  26/11/2014  22:00   increasing
11  26/11/2014  23:00   increasing
12  26/11/2014  00:00   increasing
13  26/11/2014  01:00   increasing
14  26/11/2014  02:00   increasing
15  26/11/2014  03:00   increasing
16  26/11/2014  04:00   increasing
17  26/11/2014  05:00   increasing
18  26/11/2014  06:00   increasing
19  26/11/2014  07:00   increasing
20  26/11/2014  08:00   increasing
```

Comment: I don't really know any way that would handle it in virtually all cases without `VBA`.

Comment: OK. I'm ready to use VBA in excel....

Comment: in your output sample.. line 12.. it should be 27/11/2014 right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the location of your original data :

```
B2  --->  26/11/2014 13:00
B3  --->  26/11/2014 20:00
C2  --->  26/11/2014 20:00
C3  --->  27/11/2014 09:00
D2  --->  decreasing
D3  --->  increasing
```

And in sheet2, put some labels :

```
B1  --->  date
C1  --->  hour
D1  --->  value
```

Some date generator.. Assuming Sheet1!B2 is the start date..

```
B2  --->  =DATE(YEAR(Sheet1!B2),MONTH(Sheet1!B2),DAY(Sheet1!B2))
C2  --->  =TIME(HOUR(Sheet1!B2),MINUTE(Sheet1!B2),SECOND(Sheet1!B2))
B3  --->  =IF(INT((C2+TIME(1,0,0)))>INT(C2),B2+1,B2)
C3  --->  =IF((TIME(HOUR(C2),MINUTE(C2),SECOND(C2))+TIME(1,0,0))>1,TIME(HOUR(C2),MINUTE(C2),SECOND(C2))+TIME(1,0,0)-1,TIME(HOUR(C2),MINUTE(C2),SECOND(C2))+TIME(1,0,0))
```

and lastly, using and Sheet1!C3 as the end date, define output.

```
D2  --->  =IF((B2+IF(C2=1,0,C2))<Sheet1!$C$3,IF((B2+IF(C2=1,0,C2))<Sheet1!$C$2,Sheet1!$D$2,Sheet1!$D$3),"")
```

drag the until E21. Done.

I hope that'll help. Do buzz me if there is any part of the formula that you can't understand. ( :